# Cannot convert value of type '[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?' to specified type 'NSMutableArray'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a class subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout and i have defined the `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` method

And inside i am trying to make a NSMutable array so i can enumerate the objects.

the code for this is below

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    // I get the error at this line
    var attributes : NSMutableArray = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
}
```

i cant subclass the attributes element as UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes as i would not be able to enumerate through it with a block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an NSMutableArray why don't you use:

```
var attributes : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect))
```

The code you have now expects an NSMutableArray but receives an array of UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

Comment: This is because Swift Array is always bridged to NSArray.